# The document NSBundle.h could no be saved

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, filesystems, bundle

I'm having some troubles with the bundle and somehow I can't save images from bundle to docs directory any more. Now I've got this error before building:

> The document NSBundle.h could no be
>   saved

It apparently compiles well.
This is the kind of code I'm using:

```
//Get every name from plist array and append it to the full path
for( NSString *aName in namesPackage ) {

    bundlePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:aName ofType:@"png"];
    if([fileManager fileExistsAtPath:bundlePath])NSLog(@"it exists in bundle:  %@",bundlePath);
    imagePath = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/%@/%@",DOCUMENTS_FOLDER,package,aName];

    [fileManager copyItemAtPath:bundlePath toPath:imagePath error:&anError];
    if(anError) NSLog([anError description]);
}
```

Thanks for your help in advance.

Comment: It's ok, somehow I changed something in the NSBundle header file and Xcode was trying to save it

Comment: What kind of runtime errors and/or NSLog output are you seeing?

Answer (score 1):

You should use NSString's file extensions category:

```
-stringByAppendingPathComponent:
-stringByAppendingPathExtension:
```

That will take care of any potential issues with trailing slashes, etc.

Also, you should **never** pass any unknown string as the format argument to any variable length function, as they could contain format specifiers. Use NSLog(@"%@", anError) instead.